# Postfix: "hostname x does not resolve to address y" warning even though it does

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, multi-homed

Postfix log shows lots of these:

```
warning: hostname client.lab.lan does not resolve to address 192.168.1.153
```

Yet a DNS lookup from the server shows that it does resolve:

```
# nslookup client.lab.lan
Server:         192.168.10.242
Address:        192.168.10.242#53

Name:   client.lab.lan
Address: 192.168.1.153
Name:   client.lab.lan
Address: 192.168.10.4
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the multiple A records, but no idea how to fix it.

Any hints on how to just disable that warning would be appreciated too.

Comment: Are you not the administrator of the DNS server? The way to fix multiple records is to remove the extraneous records.

Comment: There are no extraneous records. As far as I know, having multiple A records is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that there are multiple A records means that you have a roughly 50% chance of getting one or the other.  You can either (a) remove one of the `A` records or (b) create the appropriate `PTR` records so that both addresses reverse to the correct value.

Comment: I have valid PTR records for both A records. Those would only affect revers lookups though wouldn't they? Postfix appears to be complaining about a forward lookup.

Comment: Possibly, given an ip address, it (a) first does a reverse lookup on that to get a hostname and then (b) does a forward lookup on that to see if it matches the ip address used in (a).